# how to list Authorization Policies a user is satisfying

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, authorization

I'm building a Blazor Server .net 7 app and would like to list on a "user profile" page the policies the user's claims are satisfying. This list should be dynamic so that as new policies are added (in Program.cs), the "user profile" page would simply grow with the list of policies.

I've set up a few policies like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AD-Group1", policy =>
                  policy.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", "S-1-5-21-9999999999-9999999999-9999999999-99999"));

    options.AddPolicy("AD-Group2", policy =>
                  policy.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", "S-1-5-21-9999999999-9999999999-9999999999-88888"));
```

So the User Profile page that looks like this:
AD-Policy1: Yes
AD-Policy2: No

I know I can use **user.HasClaim** to determine if the user has this claim, but I don't know how to dynamically retrieve the list of policies that were set up during **builder.Services.AddAuthorization**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the implementation of [`AuthorizationOptions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d19463b38a4001104e64b0b6867ae0c73b235e2c/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationOptions.cs) you can see that there is a `Dictionary` of policies maintained which holds all the registered policies and is filled when `AddPolicy()` is called. However, this dictionary `PolicyMap` is private and there is no public method which would allow to fetch all the registered policies. Therefore although you could inject `IOptions<AuthorizationOptions>` e.g. in a service, this service will not have access to this dictionary or its contents.

One way to retrieve a list of policies therefore would be to use Reflection to access the private property `PolicyMap`. That method obviously isn't very nice since it relies on implementation details which you do not have control over and since it uses reflection will be rather slow.

`Program.cs`

```cs
using Test.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x =>
{
    // 1 requirement
    x.AddPolicy("x", o => o.RequireClaim("Requirement1"));
    x.AddPolicy("y", o =>
    {
        // here we have two requirements
        o.RequireClaim("Requirement1");
        o.RequireClaim("Requirement2");
    });
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PolicyService>();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", (PolicyService service) =>
{
    var policies = service.GetPolicies();
    var result = policies.Select(x => new
    {
        PolicyName = x.Key,
        RequirementsCount = x.Value!.Requirements.Count
    });
    return Results.Ok(result);
});

app.Run();
```

`PolicyService.cs`

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Test.Services;

class PolicyService
{
    private readonly AuthorizationOptions _options;

    public PolicyService(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy?> GetPolicies()
    {
        var policyMapProperty = _options
            ?.GetType()
            .GetProperty("PolicyMap", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(policyMapProperty);
        var policyMapGetter = policyMapProperty.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(policyMapGetter);
        var policyMap = policyMapGetter.Invoke(_options, null) as Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy?>;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(policyMap);
        return policyMap.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

This endpoint would return

```json
[
    {
        "policyName": "x",
        "requirementsCount": 1
    },
    {
        "policyName": "y",
        "requirementsCount": 2
    }
]
```

Another option would be to maintain a list of those authorization policies yourself (essentially the same way that `AuthorizationOptions` works).

You might also be interested in [Custom Authorization Policy providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which you can implement instead of (or together with) the standard `DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Mushroomator that worked great! All I had to do was add the following line to my page and do a foreach loop on "policies".    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy?> policies = policyService.GetPolicies();